# f2py complication due parameter array dimensions being defined in modules / common blocks

Tags: fortran, fortran90, f2py

I have the following subroutine in Fortran 90:

```
subroutine foo(bar)

  use spam ! dimension n is defined in the module spam

  implicit none

  real*8 bar(n)
  ....
end subroutine foo
```

Since the array dimension `n` is defined in module `spam`, I am getting errors during the compilation of the C wrapper functions (generated by `f2py`), like

```
error: ‘n’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Because the C wrapper function does not have any reference to `spam` or `n`.

What should be the solution to this?

I am currently preparing the bindings for ginormous Fortran program, a program which I have not authored. I now think that it is bad practice to pass information regarding parameters in common blocks/modules, just because it can lead to problems like this.

Is there any workaround, or do I have to refactor the whole code to add array dimensions as parameters?

Also, there is no chance of modifying the C source, because it is auto generated by `f2py`.

Comment: How do you compile the C wrapper, you do not specify it in your question anywhere.

Comment: Also, some shared "global" variables can be very useful, I would not call it bad practice without carefully studying the code and examining other possibilities. Of course, a variable called just `n` probably shouldn't be global.

Comment: I don't write the wrapper, ``f2py`` does that for me. There is no chance of global variables, I don't have control over the C side. I can only modify my Fortran source, and you can do that in Fortran 90 through modules, that is the point. I also don't understand why I get -2 for pointing out a possible deficiency on ``f2py``'s side, i.e. the wrapper being able to see the definitions in module's scope.

Comment: The word `f2py` doesn't appear in your question, you speak about some C wrapper.

Comment: It was only in the title, I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mod.f90

```
module m
  integer :: n = 1
end module
```

main.f90

```
subroutine s
  use m
  real :: a(n)
  print *,n
end subroutine
```

python:

```
f2py -c -m main mod.f90 main.f90


ipython

In [1]: import main

In [2]: main.s()
       1

In [3]: main.m.n=5

In [4]: main.s()
           5
```

I don't see any problem in using module variables.

**---Edit---**

I can confirm the problem with explicit size array dummy arguments, when the size depends on a module variable (not a named constant), i.e.:

```
subroutine s(a)
  use m, only: n
  real :: a(n)
end subroutine
```

One way of avoid the explicit bounds is using assumed shape arrays (`a(:)`). The assumed size arrays require an explicit interface, so they must be placed in a module which the calling code uses, or an interface block has to be supplied. Modules are generally preferred.

Comment: Yeah indeed. Since I have lots of files, I am using a separate signature file. I also use ``numpy.distutils`` to build, I will look at which commands are passed to f2py. I am running some tests, will tell when I finish.

Comment: Ok, try making ``a`` a parameter like ``subroutine s(a)``. Then you should get the error that n is undefined.

Comment: Really? Have you tried deleting the compiled file before recompiling, because I get this error: http://pastebin.com/n4qzUY8Q

Comment: Could you send me your ``mainmodule.c`` using pastebin or something else. You can generate those in the current dir by omitting the ``-c`` flag.

Comment: I am using Arch, also tried on an Ubuntu machine. I get the same errors.

Comment: Interesting, my line 179 says ``a_Dims[0]=(n);`` whereas yours says ``a_Dims[0]=1;``. Could you update your answer with your latest code? Also, thanks for sticking with me.

Comment: I get the same code as you when I use ``real :: a(1)`` in the subroutine

Comment: It makes sense, because the named constant is changed to its value by the compiler, the code is in the answer.

Comment: I see. The parameter specification makes n a constant and the compiler then assigns its value. But it is vital for me that n is not constant, and is modifiable by the subroutines that use the module. So I think you would be able to reproduce my error if you remove ``parameter`` from n's definition.

Comment: But the first example doesn't have the `parameter`, you just requested me to try it.

Comment: I meant "parameter to the subroutine" as in s (a). Sorry, I don't know the exact fortran terminology.

Comment: Indeed, I get the error, when the array is a dummy argument and `n` is a variable. Can't you just use assumed shape arrays? (`dimension(:)`)

Comment: Or just `dimension(*)` could be OK.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54380/discussion-between-nrs-and-vladimir-f).