# Throwing an error if any procedure interface is not explicitly defined, or in a module in Fortran 90+

Tags: fortran, fortran90

In the article [Mistakes in Fortran 90 Programs That Might Surprise You](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~szymansk/OOF90/bugs.html)

There is this following section,

> **Danger of calling Fortran 90 style routines**
>
> ```
>       program main
>       real, dimension(5) :: x
>
>       x = 0.
> ! THIS IS WRONG
>       call incb(x)
>       print *, x
>
>       end program main
>
>       subroutine incb(a)
> ! this is a fortran90 style subroutine
>       real, dimension(:) :: a
>       a = a + 1.
>       end subroutine incb
> ```
>
> Explanation The subroutine incb uses a Fortran 90 style assumed shape
>   array (containing dimension(:)). Such routines must either be in a
>   module, or have an explicit interface wherever they are used. In this
>   example, neither one was true.
>
> One correct way to call such procedures is to use an explicit
>   interface as follows:
>
> ```
>       program main
>       real, dimension(5) :: x
>
> ! THIS IS THE RIGHT WAY
>       interface
>          subroutine incb(a)
>            real, dimension(:) :: a
>          end subroutine incb
>       end interface
>
>       x = 0.
>       call incb(x)
>       print *, x
>
>       end program main
>
>       subroutine incb(a)
> ! this is a fortran90 style subroutine
>       real, dimension(:) :: a
>       a = a + 1.
>       end subroutine incb
> ```
>
> If the routine is in a module interfaces are generated automatically
>   and do not need to be explicitly written.
>
> ```
> ! THIS IS ANOTHER RIGHT WAY
>       module inc
>       contains
>       subroutine incb(a)
> ! this is a fortran90 style subroutine
>       real, dimension(:) :: a
>       a = a + 1.
>       end subroutine incb
>       end module inc
>
>       program main
>       use inc
>       real, dimension(5) :: x
>
>       x = 0.
>       call incb(x)
>       print *, x
>
>       end program main
> ```
>
> If interfaces are used, the interface MUST match the actual function.

So continuing my question, is there an option in `gfortran` or other compilers to prevent compilation if there is a call to a procedure whose interface is not explicity defined (or defined in a module)?

If not, shouldn't it be a feature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For gfortran there is the compile option `-Wimplicit-interface`:

> -Wimplicit-procedure
>       Warn if a procedure is called that has neither an explicit interface nor has been declared as EXTERNAL.

This can be coupled with `-Werror` to treat this as an error.

On compiling this (with gfortran 4.8.2)

```
  call heffalump(1)
end
```

one sees

> call heffalump(1)
>                      1
>   Warning: Procedure 'heffalump' called with an implicit interface at (1)

Do note, however, that although this can be a useful test for "silly mistakes" in newly developed modern code, things can be quite correct and still fail this test.  See also Vladimir F's comment to this answer.

Of course, a compiler in most circumstances can't tell whether the procedure requires an explicit interface.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23875494/3157076) for options to allow the compiler to do a little extra work in that regard.

Comment: Be careful, this checks much more and can introduce a lot of noise. I use it, but it is totally unusable for many older programs, which use many legitimate implicit procedures or procedures with implicit interfaces. Especially with -Werror` you will get crazy with many perfectly standard conforming codes.

Comment: I fully agree: it's an answer to the question, but I really don't recommend this.  I think I'll stress that more in the answer itself, thanks.

Comment: Not only for silly mistakes, but I think it will become essential, because I am refactoring and modernizing a Fortran 77 code. I am going to use assumed shape arrays, which means that implicit interfaces can cause memory leaks anywhere. So no loose ends. You can refer to my previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23848349/1350116

Comment: @nrs It's now very hard for me to say `-Werror` as that destroys your ability to do the refactoring incrementally.  If you change the question from `prevent compilation if ...` to `warn if ...` I'll hack that chunk out of my answer and keep everyone happy.  [I put that there only through being very literal.]

Comment: I agree, but I think this is a bug (or lack of feature) that needs to be addressed, unless introduction of ``-Werror=*`` breaks anyones workflow. Maybe I can post in the mailing lists? I feel like the question should stay as it is, but I can change if you really insist on it.

Comment: Also just ``-Werror`` was not enough for me to throw an error, I also had to supply ``-Wextra``. Can you confirm this?

Comment: @nrs When I tested without `-Wextra` compilation did cease, but there was no additional error message.  Is this what you expect?  [I no longer have access to my machine with gfortran.]

Comment: I mistook the abscence of the error message as success, it indeed throws the error without a message. Ok, got it

Answer (score 5):

Yes compilers do have this. Ifort has `-warn interfaces`, included in `-warn`, gfortran has this check in `-Wall`.

```
interf.f90:6.15:

      call incb(x)
               1
Error: Procedure 'incb' at (1) with assumed-shape dummy argument 'a' must have an explicit interface
```

The compiler will have however problem checking this if they reside in different files. Some will find it, some will not.

```
> gfortran incb.f90 interf.f90 -Wall
> ifort incb.f90 interf.f90 -warn
interf.f90(6): error #7978: Required interface for passing assumed shape array is missing from original source   [X]
      call incb(x)

----------------^
compilation aborted for interf.f90 (code 1)
```

As @francesalus writes you can force warnings for implicit interfaces `-Wimplicit-interface`. This however does something different. It warns for *EVERY* procedure with implicit interface, even when it is standard conforming to have it.

If you connect it with `-Werror` you will have to write an interface for every MPI procedure that works with buffers, to every legacy library you use. I use it, but my code is strictly in modules and I really had to wrote the interfaces to every MPI procedure I use, that sends or receives some buffer. For every type of the buffer, you need separate interface (at least in current Fortran 2008).

Even worse, some MPI implementations supply explicit interfaces to certain procedures and some do not. Once you make the effort to declare the requires interfaces for one MPI library version, another one will start to complain that the interface is already defined and they differ. (Actual story from the trenches.)

Comment: I found out that gfortran specifically requires these two flags: ``-Wextra -Wimplicit-interface``. Could you add them to the answer? Could you also mention that gfortran lacks the some of the flag functionality its C counterpart has, like ``-Werror=implicit-interface`` produces no results, or ``-Wimplicit-interface`` by itself gives the warning but does not cause an error.

Comment: I know them, but cannot recommend for you, but I will describe them.

Comment: Fortran becomes more and more interesting every day. So implicit interfaces to procedure calls are considered standard conforming, but discouraged, right? This should be due to backwards compatibility to Fortran 77. Nonetheless, these are still caveats for beginners like me. Have I understood correctly?

Comment: Yes, mostly for backwards compatibility. But MPI would be difficult to use otherwise. Explicit interfaces to these generic (or better typeless?) procedures written in C will be possible only using a new technical standard that extends Fortran 2008.