# ifort command-line vs Visual Studio (assumed shape array)

Tags: visual-studio, fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

Recently I encountered the following issue:

I made this very simple program in Visual Studio Enterprise 2022, Intel® Fortran Compiler Classic 2021.10.0, Windows 10:

```
program test
    implicit none
    integer, dimension(3):: x=[1, 2, 3]
    integer, external:: f
    integer:: y

    y = f(x)
end program test

integer function f(x) result(r)
    implicit none
    integer, dimension(:), intent(in):: x
    
    print*, x(2)
    r=2
end function f
```

To my surprise, it compiled and ran perfectly. I say to my surprise because to my understanding, this is not standard Fortran. And sure enough when I tried to compile it with gfortran it does throw an error telling me to use an interface. To make things worse, when I tried to compile it with command line ifort it did compile it but the executable wouldn't ran, with a "Program Exception - access violation" error.

*Sidenote: If I replace the function with a subroutine then gfortran and ifort IDE throw the same error ("use an interface") but ifort in command-line still compiles it fine but can't run the executable.*

So here are my questions:

1. Why all those difference behaviours (I know gfortran is the correct/standrad one)? I would at least expect the two iforts (IDE and cmd) to have the same effects.
2. How can I force Visual studio to run ifort in the standard protocol (I tried adding the /stand switch but it didn't work)?
3. How can I make command-line ifort to run this code (since evidently, with the proper flags it can run it)

Here are the switches that the Visual Studio uses, which none of them should contribute to this behaviour I think:

[image]

Comment: A compiler can do absolutely anything it likes with your source code. Fortran compilers are constrained by the standard mainly when given a Fortran program, but you don't give it a Fortran program.

Comment: @francescalus what do you mean I don't give it a Fortran program?

Comment: See, for example, [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57558684/3157076). There's nothing here where gfortran is doing the correct thing and ifort the wrong, or that any two different versions of ifort should do the same thing.

Comment: You say yourself "to my understanding, this is not standard Fortran": you have something Fortran-ish, but not Fortran.

Comment: At a practical level, you may have some success with [`-warn interfaces`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23873133/3157076) applied to the command line, like you have with the IDE.

Comment: The program is not legal Fortran, that means that anything can happen. The Fortran standard does not describe what should happen for such code. See also the concept of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior in other programming languages.

Comment: @francescalus I'm guessing you're talking about the absence of an interface. I am aware that this is not standard Fortran (which I mention in my question). My confusion is with the behaviour of the various compilers. I would expect a compiler to, at least, warn you of non-standard code if not outright throwing an error. But evidently, gfortran does tell you that this is a wrong (non-standard) code, why ifort doesn't? An even worse ifort IDE even runs fine. So I still have the same questions as in my original post

Comment: @Monochromatic The compilers are required to diagnose only certain specific kinds of non-conformance and to issue errors for them. But the set is relatively limited.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I get the concept of undefined behavior. But that still doesn't answer the different behavior of gfortran, ifort cmd and ifort IDE. And more importanly it doesn't answer my second and third question of how can I set the ifort compiler (both cmd and IDE) to not compile standard code

Comment: @Monochromatic Anything can happen and the circumstances when exactly what will happen could be completely undpredictable.  When the behaviour is undefined, you simply cannot ask ano compiler does A and why the other does B. The question does not have any sense unless the compiler athors explicitly decided to fix the behaviour in some way (very unlikely here).

Comment: @francescalus the /warn:interfaces does seem to make the command-line ifort to compile the code fine (by creting an interface module), so that answers my third question. So if I set warn:none in visual studio then the code compiles but doesn't run. So I guess I have all my questions answered. Still though it seems counterintuitive to me. To have the flag warn:interfaces not just warn you but actively "correcting" the code is wrong in my opinion.

Comment: How did you conclude that the compiler makes such a module for you?

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава If you compile the above program with ifort /warn:interface it will create a .f90 file in the same directory that looks like this:

https://pastebin.com/m077ADn9

Comment: In the most general sense, it's impossible to tell the compiler not to compile non-standard code.  Often one of the main reasons for it being nonstandard is because it is excessively difficult (or even impossible, also see "halting problem") to detect and diagnose the violation.

Comment: That is interesting. I do sometimes use `-warn` and never realized it will automatically do this without even displaying a warning. I agree that silently correcting the missing explicit interface is not right IMHO.

Comment: @Craig may be so. But evidently gfortran can tell the difference and throws and error. And it seems that you can make ifort to also build code that is not "runnable", but with a pretty backwards way (in my opinion). As I stated above, having /warn:interfaces actually "fixing" your code is really bad I think, especially for a language like Fortran. I could understand this kind of behaviour in a language like javascript or even Python